# weighted intervals shifting, finding optimal distribution

Tags: algorithm, optimization, intervals, weighted

I'm looking for algorithm name (if it already exists) or some hints to solve this problem.

I have set of N jobs, each job contains intervals, which may or may not overlap. All intervals within one particular job have same weight, length and maximum shift value.
And what I want is to find best (or close to best) distribution by shifting all intervals from one job to minimize peaks. You can only shift intervals forward (positive value). The output of this algorithm would be values of shifted intervals.

**Example:**
[image: image with intervals before optimization]
We have jobs A, B and C.
job A: length=2, weight=1, max shift=0 (cannot be moved)
job B: length=1, weight=3, max shift=2
job C: length=3.5, weight=5, max shift=15

[image: image with intervals after optimization]

As you can see in the first picture, there were three peaks (first between 2 and 3, second just before 4 and last peak was around 6). 
After optimization in the second picture, you can see that two of three peaks were removed by shifting intervals B and C by some value. The second peak cannot be optimized because intervals in job C overlap and we can only move all intervals at once. 
The output for this example would be: job A: 0, job B: 1.5, job C: 9.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a share-aware algorithm for machine colocation:http://people.cs.umass.edu/~ramesh/Site/PUBLICATIONS_files/SindelarSS11.pdf.